# XPath - attribute wildcard not returning element with attribute named value

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to use XPath (Java) to get all unknown nodes based on unknown attributes starting with a specific value.  For some reason, it is not returning a node that contains an attribute named `value`.  I also tested at [www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and got the same result.  Here is what I have:

**XML:**

```
<div>
    <object data="/v1/assets/mp4Video-1" type="video/mp4">
        <param name="webmSource" value="/v1/assets/webmVideo-1" type="REF"/>
    </object>
</div>
```

**XPath Expression:**

```
//*[starts-with(@*, '/v1/assets/')]
```

**Results -** returns the `<object>`, but not the `<param>`.

Now, if I change the XPath expression to `//*[starts-with(@*, '/v1/assets/') or starts-with(@value, '/v1/assets/')]`, it returns both as expected.

I guess my question is, what is it about the `value` attribute that causes XPath to not properly recognize it as an attribute, or to not return the element when the `value` attribute contains the value I am querying for?

Comment: When I use the website you linked, with the xml and xpath expression you wrote, I get both the object and param elements in the response.

Comment: @Sanj - his xpath returns the Object element, which also return its children

Comment: @PhilVallone ah ok, understand now, looks like your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your original path expression:

```
//*[starts-with(@*, '/v1/assets/')]
```

does not work has to do with how functions in XPath 1.0 cope with more nodes than expected. The `starts-with()` function expects a single node as its first argument, and a string (or a node that evaluates to a string) as its second argument.

But in the expression above, `starts-with()` is handed a *set* of attribute nodes, `@*`, as its first argument. In this case, only the *first* of those attribute nodes is used by this function. All other nodes in the set are ignored. Since the order of attributes is not defined in XML, the XPath engine is free to choose any attribute node to be used in the function. But your specific XPath engine (and many others) appear to consistently use the *first* attribute node, in the order of their appearance.

To illustrate this (and to prove it), change your input document to

```
<div>
    <object data="other" type="/v1/assets/mp4Video-1">
        <param name="/v1/assets/webmVideo-1" value="other" type="REF"/>
    </object>
</div>
```

as you can see, I have changed the order of attributes, and the attribute containing `/v1/assets/` is now the *second* attribute of the `object` element, and vice versa for the `param` element. Using this input document, your original XPath expression will only return the `param` element.

Again, this behaviour is not necessarily consistent between different XPath engines! Using other implementations of XPath might yield different results.

---

The XPath expression that does what you need is

```
//*[@*[starts-with(., '/v1/assets/')]]
```

in plain English, it says

> select elements anywhere in the document, but only if, among all attribute nodes of an element, there is an attribute whose value starts with "/v1/assets/".

Comment: Awesome explanation.  Makes perfect sense now.  Thanks.  I will have to mark this one as the accepted answer for the great explanation even though @PhilVallone did provide me with the correct answer first.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
//@*[starts-with(., '/v1/assets/')]
```

Returns all the attributes

```
//*[@*[starts-with(., '/v1/assets/')]]
```

Returns all the Elements

This will search all attributes for all nodes.

Comment: wouldn't this just return the attributes rather than the element the attribute belongs to?  I need the elements returned.

Comment: Updated to to return all the elements

Comment: ok, your second one does exactly what I am looking for.  Can you explain why it works different than mine?

Comment: @Ashaelon See my explanation, it's an interesting phenomenon.

Comment: Thanks Phil for the correct answer.  I wish I could mark both as accepted answers since you provided the solution first, but unfortunately @Mathias gave a very good explanation as to why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Then let's try to balance that , +1 :-).

Comment: @MathiasMüller I returned the favor